# Retrieving Date in ASP

Tags: asp-classic

I want to retrieve the moth from a date(in textbox),then

If that retrieved month is January ,some functions have to be added.

```
CurrDate =session("txtdateFrom")
CurrMonthID=session("txtdateTo")
CurrMonthName=MonthName("CurrMonthID")


iF CurrMonthName=January                      /* This portion have error */

/*   some functions  */

else if CurrMonthName= February

/*  some functions */
```

Comment: Go ahead & accept the answer, if it solves your problem. Click on the checkbox image next to the answer to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MonthName` function returns the name of the month in string format. Hence,

```
If lcase(CurrMonthName) = "january" Then
....
else if lcase(CurrMonthName) = "february" Then
```

However, I suggest using `Month` function that will return you the number for the month.
So, the code will look like

dim monthNum = Month(myDate)

```
if monthNum = 1 Then
....
else if monthNum = 2 Then
```